# javascript Change variable gradually over five seconds

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a beginner when it comes to JavaScript. I'm trying to change the value of a progress bar from 100 to 0 in five seconds and I can't get it to work right. I tried this [tutorial](http://www.onlywebpro.com/2011/09/09/html5-progress-bar/) but there was no way to control the time. I have a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Changer098/zfuTp/3/) to show what I have. I'd really appreciate any help.
My Javascript

```
var correct = "a1";
function onload()
{
var question1 = "Who was the first president?";
var answers = {
  "a1":"George Washington",
  "a2":"John Adams", 
  "a3":"Bill Clinton",
  "a4":"Richard Nixon"}; 
document.getElementById("qstn").innerHTML=question1;
document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML=answers.a1;  
document.getElementById("a2").innerHTML=answers.a2;  
document.getElementById("a3").innerHTML=answers.a3; 
document.getElementById("a4").innerHTML=answers.a4;
var bar = document.getElementById("bar").value;
}
```

with my HTML being

```
<body onload="onload()">
<p id="qstn"></p>
<button class="btn" onclick="checker()"><span id="a1"></span></button>
<button class="btn" onclick="checker()"><span id="a2"></span></button>
<button class="btn" onclick="checker()"><span id="a3"></span></button>
<button class="btn" onclick="checker()"><span id="a4"></span></button>
<progress value="100" max="100" id="bar"></progress>
</body>
```

Again, any help or comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: take a look at `setInterval`

Comment: You need to divide your 5 second interval into pieces (how many depends on the 'resolution' of your change) and then use setInterval and a call back to make the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use interval like this:

```
var max = 100;
setInterval(function(){
document.getElementById("bar").value=max;
        max = max-20;
},1000);
```

hope this help! it run on 5 second to 0 value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
setInterval(function(){bar.value--},1000);
```

`1000` denotes a second

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working fiddle for what you want :

http://jsfiddle.net/zfuTp/8/

Added code:

```
var interval = setInterval(update, 1000);
var i = 100;

function update() {
    document.getElementById("bar").style.width = (i-=20) + "%";      
    if(i<=0) clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Here, the width of the progress bar decreases by 20% on every iteration for 5 seconds.